# 18.04 LTS Samba error 'net usershare' returned error 255

Tags: networking, 18.04, samba, lts

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as my media server. I have 2 hdds that I share to a Windows PC to feed files to the Ubuntu media server. This morning I couldn't connect to one of the drives via Windows explorer. I disconnected both drives and restarted both Windows and Ubuntu. I went into Ubuntu and got the error mentioned in the title.

Here is a picture of the error. I had an issue uploading it to the forum
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdTui.jpg

The shares have worked just fine for months. No changes at all.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why that would happen to you if you are the only user but it appears you are not a member of the right group. So add your user name to the sambashare group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a david sambashare
```

You will need to logoff and log on again for group membership to take affect.